# how does canvas create polygon work?

Tags: python

I have problem with this function in python where `self.coordinates` is a list of x,y coordinates.

```
def draw_Polygon(self):
    self.canvas.create_polygon(self.coordinates, fill='gray', outline='red', width=2)
```

I got this error:

```
cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your tuple args is not populated at all. You might want to check that